# Closed question with accepted answer the top Google result

Tags: discussion

This morning I googled for "jquery find and remove all instances of class".  The top result was [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17662550/34806).  "Closed as off-topic" appears "above the fold", and there's a comment that "this can be answered with a quick google search."  And he's right, a google search that results in this very question although you have to scroll down for the answer.  I don't know how to vote to re-open or if I have the required reputation but I think this question is not so bad -- it certainly helped me.

Comment: why does it need to be reopened?  Just because it is closed doesnt mean it must/will be deleted.  that is not likely given the upvoted answer

Comment: I believe that being labeled as closed is a stigma and might prevent less persistent users from scrolling down to the answer

Comment: The vicious cycle of Stack Overflow providing an infinite feedback loop strikes again!

Answer (score 3):

I removed those comments and reopened the question. It had been closed for a reason that no longer exists. The question isn't great, but I understand it. I think it explains the problem well enough without showing the original code that anyone who knows enough HTML and JavaScript to *have* this problem is going to get where the OP is coming from. (Adding a bit of HTML example code probably would go a long way towards making sure the question stays open, though.)

Comment: Thanks glad to know my instincts were right

Comment: Would be nice if we could reword the close description to emphasize the part about having a clear problem statement. Not every question requires supporting code to be clear, scoped and answerable, even though most are overly localized enough that they do. This would benefit canonical questions in particular.

Comment: I edited the question with a bit of code in an attempt to improve the quality (sorry if it's very specific to what I'm trying to acheive)

Comment: Thanks, @GeorgeJempty that does look better. If you have a short HTML snippet that you could add, that would be an improvement as well.